# Ambiguous inheritance of function when multiple inheritance of classes that themselves have diamond inheritance in their hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, msvc12

**Word description** (*code below*): I have a library that provides a collection of classes. For each group of class we have two concrete types, (`ClassA_Partial`, `ClassA`), (`ClassB_Partial`, `ClassB`) etc. Each of these implements (`Interface_Partial`, `Interface`) respectively. Additionally, `Interface` *is a* `Interface_Partial` and each `Class?` *is a* `Class?_Partial` - creating a diamond inheritance pattern where the top is inherited virtually.

Why are`Interface_Partial` functions ambiguous when inheriting both `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

```
struct Interface_Partial
{ 
    virtual ~Interface_Partial(); 
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct Interface
    :
    virtual Interface_Partial
{
    virtual void g() = 0;
};


struct ClassA_Partial : public virtual Interface_Partial
{
    void f() {};
};


struct ClassA : public Interface, public virtual ClassA_Partial
{
    void g() {};
};

struct ClassB_Partial : public virtual Interface_Partial
{
    void f() {};
};


struct ClassB : public Interface, public virtual ClassB_Partial
{
    void g() {};
};

struct MyClass : public ClassA, public ClassB
{ }; // error C2250: MyClass : ambiguous inheritance of 'void Interface_Partial::f(void)'
```

Why can't we disambiguate the way we usually do when we inherit a common interface more than once? For example

```
struct ClassX : public Interface_Partial { void f() {} };
struct ClassY : public Interface_Partial { void f() {} };
class Another : public ClassX, public ClassY
{};

void func()
{
    // This is ok
    Another a;
    a.ClassX::f();   

    // Why would this not work?
    // unambiguously refers to the one and only f() function 
    // inherited via  ClassA
    MyClass b;
    b.ClassA::f();   
}
```

Comment: Luckily the 'library' in the above example is my own code - and I'm already getting rid of the diamond inheritance just to preserve my sanity. However - I am interested in the technical reasons why the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the virtual inheritance, there is only one vtable for the base class Interface_Partial - once you use virtual inheritance, the "virtualness" infects all derived classes at all levels

The inheritance is ambigous because `MyClass` has two different version of f() available - one from `ClassA` and one from `ClassB`. Because of the virtual inheritance of `Interface_Partial`, you have two derived-class implementations that are at the same level and are trying to override the same virtual function. Declaring a virtual base class makes all derived classes share the virtual base class, including its vtable. The shared vtable gets updated to contain the pointer of the virtual function which should be called. But since there are two equally "good" ones to choose from, there is no way to pick one over the other.

In the other example you give, `Interface_Partial` is a non-virtual base class for `ClassX` and `ClassY`, so each class is overriding a completely different virtual function. This is unambigous to the compiler, although when you call them, you have to specify which specific `f()` you want to call.

You can resolve this by providing an implementation of `f()` in `MyClass`.

Comment: I don't understand how that is different from the `Another` class example where we inherit `ClassX` and `ClassY` without ambiguity, despite having two derived class implementations at the same level. Could you clarify that a little?

Comment: So is it the case that the virtual inheritance passes down to child classes? Even if I only want to know about `ClassA` and `ClassB` - I still need to know that each of those virtually inherits `f()`, meaning that if I *non-virtual* inherit `ClassA` and `ClassB` the compiler is still trying to virtually inherit both `f()` and resolve a single function even though I actually want both `ClassA::f()` and `ClassB::f()` ?

Comment: @Zero, because of the virtual inheritance, there is only one vtable for the base class `Interface_Partial` - once you use virtual inheritance, the "virtualness" infects all derived classes at all levels.

Comment: I added your previous comment to the answer - because for me that was the one piece of information I really didn't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*To answer your both question we need to understand the working of virtual function* -

If you draw the vtable for each class than you can understand why it is throwing the ambiguous inheritance error

[image]

For **Interface_Partial**: It’s Vtable will contain the address of function f() with its own definition i.e. **Interface_Partial :: f().**

In **Interface** class/structure: It has function g() with its own definition along with inherited function f() from Interface_Partial  which it has not override . So the Vtable of **Interface** class will have address of two function as :

```
  1>    g() as  Interface :: g()

  2>    f() as  Interface_Partial :: f()
```

Now Come to **ClassA_Partial** : It has override the function f() from its parent class and gave its own definition so the vtable of **ClassA_Partial** will have functions f() as :

```
ClassA_Partial :: f()
```

Now the main Part :

If you see the **ClassA**  it has inherited from **Interface** and **ClassA_Partial** and overrides  the g() but **not f()**. So when compiler sees this, it will be confused because now it will have **two definition of f()**

```
 1> as   Interface_Partial :: f()   
 2> as   ClassA_Partial :: f()
```

Which one to choose ? Interface_Partial or ClassA_Partial ! So it throws an error even if you do as

```
 b.ClassA::f();
```

Because of two different versions of f()

Comment: I still don't fully understand your explanation. If I instantiate `ClassA` then `ClassA::f()` is unambiguous because of the virtual inhertiance, so I would still have thought `b.ClassA::f()` is unambiguous.

Comment: Because ClassA is having two definition of function f(), one from Interface_Partial and other from ClassA_Partial. Since you are inheriting Interface and ClassA_Partial using virutal so they will have one copy of function f() BUT classA_Partial has override the f() and created it's own version of f(), Now when you inherit these two Interface and ClassA_Partial, In Class A you'll get two different version of f().